# javascript how to make sure that the user input a text in username box

Tags: javascript

**Is that code right ?**
I don't know if that function is true also or what and Is it a must to put that function code in the script section

```
    <script>
 function2(un)
 {
   if (typeof un == "undefined")
   alert("enter text");
 }
</script>

<form>
 Username:
 <input type="text" name="username"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"onclick="function2(username)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: are you trying to check whether your username field is empty or not, or trying to check any particular requirement..

Comment: both, i want to know is it empty or not for username and to check the form of an email in another one

Answer (score 1):

Use the easiest HTML5 attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="username" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

HTML:

```
<form>Username:
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
  <span id="out"></span>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#username").val()) {
        $("#out").text($("#username").val());
    } else {
        alert("enter username");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

**The Code**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="username"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

*Script:*

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    var uname = $('#username').val();
    if(uname.length == 0){
        alert('empty');
    }
    else if(valid_email(uname)!=true){
        alert('invalid_email');
    }
    else{
        alert('validated');
    }
});

function valid_email(email){
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}
```

*Here is the link*
[The Code](http://jsfiddle.net/soumiksur2009/zhh26/1/)